# OpenApi (Swagger 3.0) Codegen is missing validations

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen

I have a basic problem with openapi maven codegen plugin. 
Validations annotation (maxLength, pattern) is missing in the java generated code.

Here is my pom:

```
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9</version>
    </dependency

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.11</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/customer-service-api.yaml</inputSpec>
                        <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</output>
                        <modelPackage>${default.package}.customer.model</modelPackage>
                        <generateModels>true</generateModels>
                        <generateApis>false</generateApis>
                        <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                        <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
                        <language>java</language>
                        <library>resttemplate</library>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and this is my swagger:

```
name:
  type: object
  properties:
    firstName:
      type: string
      pattern: "^[A-Z]{1,50}$"
      maxLength: 50
```

Now the generated java file is:

```
public class Name {
  @JsonProperty("firstName")
  private String firstName = null;

  @JsonProperty("middleName")
  private String middleName = null;

  @JsonProperty("lastName")
  private String lastName = null;
```

I expect to have RegularExpression on the attributes. so, I will be able to validate my java object by Java validator.

It works in RAML and its generated java code, and wondering why its not in my swagger's code.

Thanks,